# вывести ресурс по значению tv modx

Tags: php, cms, modx, revo

есть тв - одиночный список `Да==1||Нет==0`
Как вывести случайный ресурс у которого признак `тв== да`

делаю так но ничего не выходит

```
  [[getResources?
          &parents=`2`
          &tpl=`leftadsk`
          &limit=`1`
          &depth=`10`
          &includeContent=`1`
          &includeTVs=`1`
          &processTVs=`1`
          &tvPrefix=``
          &sortby=`createdon`
          &sortdir=`DESC`
          &where=`{"check1=":1}`
          ]]
```

у меня 4 таких блока и нужно вывести 4 разных ресурса по выше указанному условию

Answer (score 3):

Для фильтрации по `tv` в [getResources](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources) можно использовать параметр `&tvFilters=`. Если все остальные условия у Вас правильны, то вызов должен стать примерно таким:

```
[[!getResources?
    &parents=`2`
    &tpl=`leftadsk`
    &limit=`1`
    &depth=`10`
    &includeContent=`1`
    &includeTVs=`1`
    &processTVs=`1`
    &tvPrefix=``
    &sortby=`createdon`
    &sortdir=`DESC`
    &tvFilters=`check1==1`
]]
```

Также порекомендовал бы вам вместо `getResources` использовать [pdoResources](https://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/snippets/pdoresources). Существенных отличий в вызове и параметрах у них нет, однако `pdoResources` гораздо более производителен.

Comment: спасибо, а как вывести случайную запись и потом еще разы вывести случайны ресурс чтобы они не повторялись?